# Outlook 2010 eating emails after they are read or replied

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Going insane here. I have an employee who's outlook is having emails disappear randomly after she reads them or replies to them. It's not 100% of the time though. Seems totally random.

Backstory being she migrated computers, so i saved the .pst file and the .nk2 file and transferred them over to the new computer when setting up her email. I'm believing that its an issue related to the pst file.

**What I've Tried**

**Views.** The most common answer i found googling was the default view wasnt set to show read messages. This is definitely not the case. the views are setup as expected.

**scanpst** Out of desperation i tried to use the inbox repair tool. This seemingly made it worse? Probably not, but it definitely didnt fix it.

**reinstalling outlook**.  Now, i ended up using the same PST file because the employee stores a lot of needed emails in her deleted folder (who the hell knows why), so otherwise those would all be lost. its still happening.

**created new pst, transferred all emails to it** still happening :(

Anyone have any experience with this? I'm getting very annoyed!

Comment: Is the file/computer free of viruses and/or malware?

Comment: @CharlieRB fresh out-of-the-box computer. so i'd hope not!

Comment: But the `pst` and `nk2` file are not. Correct? Just want you to make sure there isn't something messing with it in the background. I've see it before.

Comment: @CharlieRB correct, these are from her old computer. Thats why i believe its a screwed up `pst` file

Comment: What type of account(s) do you use (POP3/IMAP/...)?

Answer (score 1):

Check all settings.  Even with a reinstall and a new .pst it's possible that some bad settings have persisted.

I'd see if auto-archive is turned on and check those settings.

Have a look through File->Options->Mail to make sure all looks correct there.

Check for any rules, and make sure they're working as expected.

If all else fails, you could completely delete her Outlook profile on that computer (Control Panel -> Mail -> Show profiles) and re-create it.